# Scalas (a,b).zipped (or Tuple2.zipped) notion using streams/infinite lists

Tags: list, scala, stream, fibonacci, infinite

here is what I thought would be a correct and useful definition of fibonacci nums in scala:

```
lazy val fibs:Stream[Int] = 0 #:: 1 #:: (fibs,fibs.tail).zipped.map(_+_)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
fibs take 10 foreach println
0
1
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at scala.collection.mutable.LazyBuilder.(LazyBuilder.scala:25)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$StreamBuilder.(Stream.scala:492)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$.newBuilder(Stream.scala:483)
    at...
```

I guess zipped doesn't work correctly with streams? Any suggestions on how to make this work, or why this doesnt( shouldn't? ) work?

Comment: I was just going to ask this _exact_ question. Cool to know somebody got here before me. +1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following works correctly

```
val fibs:Stream[Int] = 0 #:: 1 #:: (fibs zip fibs.tail).map{ case (a,b) => a+b }
```

The problem with `Tuple2.zipped` is that it assumes it can run `foreach` on sequences it's zipping. This is probably by design, as doing things the way `Stream.zip` implements it would probably give you bad performance for any finite-length `Seq` that isn't a `List` or `Stream`. (Because *most* data structures don't support an efficient implementation of `tail`.)

---

`Stream.zip` is essentially implemented as follows (though it does some stuff to make the types more general).

```
class Stream[A]{
  def zip(other:Stream[B]) =
    (this.head, other.head) #:: (this.tail zip other.tail)
}
```

Comment: Although the `lazy` qualifier in your question was unnecessary, I assure you that removing it in my answer wasn't what made this work.

Comment: Okay, what you have shown is very nice :) I guess this only goes to show how much we need a "zipWith" which takes a 2-arity function as an argument like in haskell. I really don't get why it's not there in Scala?

Comment: @Felix: I don't see how `zipWith` would help. `zipWith` on a tuple would still be implemented as a `foreach` that would overflow when the first list was an infinite stream.

Comment: You are doing it right here:

(fibs zip fibs.tail).map{ case (a,b) => a+b }

I don't see why this could not be moved to the Stream class and take a 2-arity function as a parameter?

Answer (score 3):

There's a ticket on this in Scala's Trac database: http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/2634

The ticket was closed as wontfix, but note Adriaan's "Or are we missing something?" in the comments — maybe this will get revisited someday.